# How to loop through multiple columns with same filters?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, purrr

I'm trying to see if I can use a loop using apply or purrr functions to loop through columns to filter the same data value. For example, I'm looking for a way to loop through columns Q2_1:Q2_10. Currently, I'm doing this in a highly inefficient way:

```
data %>% 
  filter(Q2_1 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_2 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_3 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_4 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_5 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_6 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_7 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_8 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_9 == 5) %>% 
  filter(Q2_10 == 5)
```

I'm not sure how to get started with the lapply or with the tidyverse way. Should I convert the filter into a function or just add the filter function into the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if_all` -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% filter(if_all(Q2_1:Q2_10, ~. == 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point:

```r
cols = c("Q2_1","Q2_2","Q2_3","Q2_4","Q2_5","Q2_6","Q2_7","Q2_8","Q2_9","Q2_10")

for(col in cols){
  data = data %>%
    filter(!!sym(col) == 5)
}
```

Note that `cols` is an array of character strings, so we use `!!sym(.)` to turn each character string into an R variable for evaluation. This feature is from the rlang package.

There are other ways to do this. See the tidyverse guidance on [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for other options & explanation.

Comment: I like this! Is there a way to loop over each column instead of the `cols = c("Q2_1", "Q2_2" . . . `?

Comment: You could use `cols = colnames(df)` to loop over all columns. Otherwise you could look into pattern matching with `grepl`.